# Typescript with atom-typescript plugin vs gulp task

Tags: typescript, gulp, atom-editor

I'm just getting into TypeScript as I am learning Angular (2.0). I'm devising the best way to compile TypeScript and how to organize my project.

I am using atom-typescript for Atom to compile the ts files with a tsconfig file, but I'm curious if I should be using a gulp task instead since I will eventually want to concatenate and uglify the js output of the ts files. As far as I know, I cannot do this with the atom-typescript plugin.
If I do start using a Gulp task, the sacrifice will be the code-hinting and feedback that atom-typescipt provides in the editor.

Or perhaps I should let the plugin do the transpiling and use gulp to uglify the resulting js. ???

Is there a happy-medium, best-practice way I should handle this?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use both? You can use Atom to edit and compile your TypeScript and Gulp task to concatenate and uglify the resulting JavaScript. That's what I do and it works great. You get linting and instant compilation, but when you're ready for production you run your Gulp task.

Comment: Yeah, your instincts were right. Just use Gulp as much as you need it. It doesn't have to do everything.